# Variable is not visible - get set

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, set, getter

I have a controller for a Visualforce page that uses a getter and setter method to initialize a custom object `Application__c` however it is throwing strange errors that I did not previously get when using getter and setter methods:

`Variable is not visible: FormClass.app`

`Variable does not exist: set`

`Missing return statement required return type: Application__c`

What am I missing here?

```
public without sharing class FormClass {
    
    //Application
    public Application__c app {
        get {
            if(app == null){    
                app = new Application__c();
            return app;
            }
        set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are screwed up; one of the ones after `set` are extra, and your `if` statement is missing a closing bracket. This causes some cascading errors.

```
public without sharing class FormClass {
    
    //Application
    public Application__c app {
        get {
            if(app == null){    
                app = new Application__c();
            } // this should be here
            return app;
        }
        set;
        // } this one is extra
    }
}
```